# Assign same value to different rows a specific number of times (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I'm going to create an users database on a website. I'm using MySQL.

Is required that when an user do the registration process in the website, the table where the users are added make the following process:

When new user is added to the table "users", in that table there is a column named "group". So is required that this field or column generates an auto increment number, but with the property of repeat every value four (4) times. And also is required to limit the registration process just for 16384 users.

e.g.:

```
id  | name      | group
1   | mark      | 1
2   | john      | 1
3   | sammy     | 1
4   | lucy      | 1
5   | richard   | 2
6   | michel    | 2
7   | jennifer  | 2
8   | mary      | 2
9   | liz       | 3
10  | mike      | 3
11  | laura     | 3
12  | astrid    | 3
```

I was searching and reading so much, but this issue seems like unique, and I have to accept that I don't understand much about this themes and I'm just now learning about MySQL and databases.

I found something in *w3school.com* this is the code modified by me a little:

Creating a form on HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP "insert.php":

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$group= (WHAT CAN I PUT HERE TO MAKE THE AUTO INCREMENT BUT REPEATING THE SAME 
NUMBER FOUR TIMES?)

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Group)
VALUES ('$name', '$group')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And what can I do here to restrict the registration just to 16384 users?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want an `update` or `select`.  Here is a `select` version:

```
select t.id, t.name,
       (case when (@rn := @rn+1) is NULL then NULL
             else floor((@rn - 1)/4)
        end) as grp
from (select t.*, 
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) var
      order by id
      limit 16384
     ) t;
```

If you can depend on the `id` column being sequential with no gaps, then you could use that instead.

If you want an `update`, you can use `update`/`join` to combine these results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is the following:

Comment: this website is to make a registration process of users that wants to participate in a game contest. So the max number of gamers allowed is 16384, and is required that every gamer has a group, and every group is just for four (4) participants

Comment: Is needed that when an user makes the registration process the system assign to him or her a group automatically. I'm making the website in Joomla! but I couldn't find any extension that do this. So I'm trying to do it directly into the database.

Comment: @user3650249 . . . You would need a trigger to assign this value inside the database on an `insert`.

Comment: Thank you for give me quick answers. I've edited the question to show you something that I found